# pure-python RNN and theano RNN computing different gradients -- code and results provided

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, theano

I've been banging my head against this for a while and can't figure out what I've done wrong (if anything) in implementing these RNNs. To spare you guys the forward phase, I can tell you that the two implementations compute the same outputs, so the forward phase is correct. The problem is in the backwards phase.

Here is my python backwards code. It follows the style of karpathy's neuraltalk quite closely but not exactly:

```
def backward(self, cache, target,c=leastsquares_cost, dc=leastsquares_dcost):
        '''
        cache is from forward pass

        c is a cost function
        dc is a function used as dc(output, target) which gives the gradient dc/doutput 
        '''
        XdotW = cache['XdotW'] #num_time_steps x hidden_size
        Hin = cache['Hin'] # num_time_steps x hidden_size
        T = Hin.shape[0]
        Hout = cache['Hout']
        Xin = cache['Xin']
        Xout = cache['Xout']

        Oin = cache['Oin'] # num_time_steps x output_size
        Oout=cache['Oout']

        dcdOin = dc(Oout, target) # this will be num_time_steps x num_outputs. these are dc/dO_j


        dcdWho = np.dot(Hout.transpose(), dcdOin) # this is the sum of outer products for all time

        # bias term is added at the end with coefficient 1 hence the dot product is just the sum
        dcdbho = np.sum(dcdOin, axis=0, keepdims=True) #this sums all the time steps

        dcdHout = np.dot(dcdOin, self.Who.transpose()) #reflects dcdHout_ij should be the dot product of dcdoin and the i'th row of Who; this is only for the outputs
        # now go back in time
        dcdHin = np.zeros(dcdHout.shape)
        # for t=T we can ignore the other term (error from the next timestep). self.df is derivative of activation function (here, tanh):
        dcdHin[T-1] = self.df(Hin[T-1]) * dcdHout[T-1] # because we don't need to worry about the next timestep, dcdHout is already corrent for t=T

        for t in reversed(xrange(T-1)):
            # we need to add to dcdHout[t] the error from the next timestep
            dcdHout[t] += np.dot(dcdHin[t], self.Whh.transpose())
            # now we have the correct form for dcdHout[t]
            dcdHin[t] = self.df(Hin[t]) * dcdHout[t]
        # now we've gone through all t, and we can continue
        dcdWhh = np.zeros(self.Whh.shape)
        for t in range(T-1): #skip T bc dHdin[T+1] doesn't exist
            dcdWhh += np.outer(Hout[t], dcdHin[t+1])
        # and we can do bias as well
        dcdbhh = np.sum(dcdHin,axis=0, keepdims=True)


        # now we need to go back to the embeddings
        dcdWxh = np.dot(Xout.transpose(), dcdHin)

        return {'dcdOout': dcdOout, 'dcdWxh': dcdWxh, 'dcdWhh': dcdWhh, 'dcdWho': dcdWho, 'dcdbhh': dcdbhh, 'dcdbho': dcdbho, 'cost':c(Oout, target)}
```

And here's the theano code (mainly copied from another implementation I found online. I initialize the weights to my pure-python rnn's randomized weights so that everything is the same.):

```
# input (where first dimension is time)
u = TT.matrix()
# target (where first dimension is time)
t = TT.matrix()
# initial hidden state of the RNN
h0 = TT.vector()
# learning rate
lr = TT.scalar()
# recurrent weights as a shared variable
W = theano.shared(rnn.Whh)
# input to hidden layer weights
W_in = theano.shared(rnn.Wxh)
# hidden to output layer weights
W_out = theano.shared(rnn.Who)

# bias 1
b_h = theano.shared(rnn.bhh[0])
# bias 2
b_o = theano.shared(rnn.bho[0])


# recurrent function (using tanh activation function) and linear output
# activation function
def step(u_t, h_tm1, W, W_in, W_out):
    h_t = TT.tanh(TT.dot(u_t, W_in) + TT.dot(h_tm1, W) + b_h)
    y_t = TT.dot(h_t, W_out) + b_o
    return h_t, y_t

# the hidden state `h` for the entire sequence, and the output for the
# entrie sequence `y` (first dimension is always time)
[h, y], _ = theano.scan(step,
                        sequences=u,
                        outputs_info=[h0, None],
                        non_sequences=[W, W_in, W_out])
# error between output and target
error = (.5*(y - t) ** 2).sum()
# gradients on the weights using BPTT
gW, gW_in, gW_out, gb_h, gb_o = TT.grad(error, [W, W_in, W_out, b_h, b_o])
# training function, that computes the error and updates the weights using
# SGD.
```

Now here's the crazy thing. If i run the following:

```
fn = theano.function([h0, u, t, lr],
                     [error, y, h, gW, gW_in, gW_out, gb_h, gb_o],
                     updates={W: W - lr * gW,
                             W_in: W_in - lr * gW_in,
                             W_out: W_out - lr * gW_out})

er, yout, hout, gWhh, gWhx, gWho, gbh, gbo =fn(numpy.zeros((n,)), numpy.eye(5), numpy.eye(5),.01)
cache = rnn.forward(np.eye(5))
bc = rnn.backward(cache, np.eye(5))

print "sum difference between gWho (theano) and bc['dcdWho'] (pure python):"
print np.sum(gWho - bc['dcdWho'])
print "sum differnce between gWhh(theano) and bc['dcdWho'] (pure python):"
print np.sum(gWhh - bc['dcdWhh'])
print "sum difference between gWhx (theano) and bc['dcdWxh'] (pure pyython):"
print np.sum(gWhx - bc['dcdWxh'])

print "sum different between the last row of gWhx (theano) and the last row of bc['dcdWxh'] (pure python):"
print np.sum(gWhx[-1] - bc['dcdWxh'][-1])
```

I get the following output:

```
sum difference between gWho (theano) and bc['dcdWho'] (pure python):
-4.59268040265e-16
sum differnce between gWhh(theano) and bc['dcdWhh'] (pure python):
0.120527063611
sum difference between gWhx (theano) and bc['dcdWxh'] (pure pyython):
-0.332613468652
sum different between the last row of gWhx (theano) and the last row of bc['dcdWxh'] (pure python):
4.33680868994e-18
```

So, I'm getting the derivatives of the weight matrix between the hidden layer and output right, but not the derivatives of the weight matrix hidden -> hidden or input -> hidden. But this insane thing is that I ALWAYS get the LAST ROW of the weight matrix input -> hidden correct. This is insanity to me. I have no idea what's happening here. Note that the last row of the weight matrix input -> hidden does NOT correspond to the last timestep or anything (this would be explained, for example, by me calculating the derivatives correctly for the last timestep but not propagating back through time correctly). dcdWxh is the sum over all time steps of dcdWxh -- so how can I get one row of this correct but none of the others???

Can anyone help? I'm all out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

You should compute the sum of the **pointwise absolute value** of the difference of the two matrices. The plain sum could be close to zero due to the specific learning tasks (do you emulate the zero function? :), whichever that is.

The last row presumably implements the weights from a constant-on-neuron, i.e. the bias, so you - seem to - always get the bias right (however, check the sum of absolute values) .

It also looks like row-major and column-major notation of matrices are confused, like in

```
gWhx - bc['dcdWxh']
```

which reads like weight from "hidden to x" in opposite to "x to hidden".

I'd rather post this as a comment, but I lack the reputation in doing so. sorry!